# How to use eclipse CDT for jni debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface

How to use Eclipse CDT along with JDT to debug the jni code?

Using Eclipse, is there a way by which we can debug the native code without the use of visual studio?

Thanks.